# growth rate of functions more then 10

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

am trying to Separately the groups of functions that grow at the same rate,

- (√2)log2n;
- n^2;
- n!;
- (log2 n)!;
- (log2 n)!;
- 3/2^n;
- n^3;
- (log2 n)^2;
- log2(n!);
- 2^2^n;
- n^1/ log2 n;
- ln ln n;
- n · 2^n;
- n^log2log2 n;
- ln n;
- 1;
- 2^log2 n;
- (log2 n)^log2 n;
- e^n;
- (2n)!!;
- (√log2 n);
- 2^√2 log2 n;
- n log2 n ;
- 2n;
- n;

I know when we compare about 2 functions that we using l'hospital rule and function fx is growing faster than gx if the result was infinite, and if it 0 that mean they growing at the same rate,

but am struggling with when we have more than n > 2 functions and which order we using l'hospital rule hope to guide me;

Comment: You can compare growth rates like an equality/inequality. You could write f > g to mean f grows faster than g, or f=g to mean f grows the same as g. Then all the rules about inequalities/ equalities apply. Suppose you want to compare 3 functions say f,g,h. If f grows faster than g, and g grows faster than h, then you can conclude f grows faster than h. Or if you knew f grows the same as g and g grows the same as h, then f grows the same as h.

Comment: In fact you can use a binary search style comparison to get each placed quickly ...

Comment: but how  to Separately the groups of functions that grow at the same rate,